# Access parent template data with Flow Router

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper, flow-router

I switched to Flow Router and I have a problem. how can I access the parent template data? with Iron Router the data was coming from router and was available inside the template, so if I wanted to access a parent data Template.parentData() was working. 
But in Flow Router the data is not coming from router, it comes from helpers and Template.parentData() doesn't have the data in it anymore!

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{> showPost parentPost }}
      {{> newPost }}
    {{/if}}  
</template>

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    parentPost: function(){ return Posts.findOne({...})}
});

Template.newPost.events({
    'submit .js-new-post':function(event,template){
         console.log(Template.parentData(1).parentPost);
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass that data through to the Template.

E.g. `{{> newPost parentPost=mydatahere}}`

See more here: http://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#name-data-contexts

Comment: thanks for the tip but by naming it, it just get named on the child template (newPost) and parent template still doesn't include the data!!

Comment: Then you aren't passing through the right data to the child template.

Comment: did you look at the code?? my problem is not that data is not available in the child, problem is the data is not available in the sibling template with parentData()

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Because I've done the exact thing you're attempting to do. And I did it by passing the data context of the parent template (myTemplate) into the child template (newPost). Did you read the Meteor guide link I sent you?

Comment: my bad, so you are suggesting that I pass the data into the sibling template that doesn't need the data as well? so I pass parenPost data to both of my child templates?

Comment: this will work as a work around but I prefer to use parentData() if possible and don't litter the templates data for an event that may or may not happen.

Comment: Well, the mydatahere can be a helper that could do some logic if needed or remove any data that's not needed for your event to function.

Comment: How big are your documents? And are you displaying lots at once? If not the additional data in the child should be negligible. Setting parent data with IR would have automatically passed it through to your child anyway as the context so there would be no difference from what you were previously doing. A low data alternative would be to pass just the _id of your doc and do a findOne in your submit as the data should already be in minimongo you won't need to subscribe and look up time should be lightning fast from minimongo as it's already clientside so `{{ newPost id= parentPost._id }}`.