# React Mounter, Flow Router, Use with Stateful Components

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router, meteor-react

With React Mounter and Flow Router, all the tutorials I have found so far show how to use these tools with stateless components. However, how does one use it with stateful components that are written like:

```
App = React.createClass({

  onClicked() {
    if(this.state.visible) {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ visible : true });
    }
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried something that isn't working? I can't see any problems with that snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access parent template data with Flow Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272368/access-parent-template-data-with-flow-router)